# Syntax error: print yaml.dump( on repl.it

Tags: python, replit

I need help fixing this error I keep getting in repl.it, here's the error, I broke it down into its key components:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/universe/__init__.py", line 227
    print yaml.dump(
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code I used (I created it in repl.it):

```
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('flashgames.CoasterRacer-V0')
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  observation_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

Can you please help me?

here's the repl.it link, put your edits into changes.txt;
https://repl.it/@32_bits_in_a_by/to-be-fixed

Comment: Link to the repl.it job? Your code contains indentation problems which cause a syntax error; please [edit] to fix it.

Comment: the link is https://repl.it/@32_bits_in_a_by/to-be-fixed

Comment: What you need is https://github.com/openai/universe, but repl.it installed https://github.com/fclaerho/ansible-universe for you, so it won't work.

Comment: @shaunshia That looks like something you could post as an answer. However, I get a different error if I try `import pip; pip.main(["install", "--user", "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/5e/26ee56c16cdc83a07a3251e3425856f2ade84928de55b3fa11590ce2b912/universe-0.21.3.tar.gz"])` at the repl.it command prompt (`make` not installed).

Comment: Thanks, because I don't know how to actually solve it. I didn't use `universe` before, but it looks like a gigantic application which requires some native dependencies as in their README `sudo apt-get install golang libjpeg-turbo8-dev make`

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that `universe` is Python 2 only.

Comment: thank you for telling me, I hope that it will work, if it does not then I will message you back, thanks

Comment: Notice the comment from @shaunshia also. The component which is Py2-only is actually `ansible-universe`.